# Proper use of TableAlignment

Tags: list-manipulation, alignment

At various times though use of extensive trial-and-error I have gotten results I want out of TableHeadings. More often I give up. For example, given two columns, (a) how does one make the first left-justified and the second right-justified? And (b) is there any elegant way of aligning to the decimal point?

```
inTable={{"one","two","three","four","five"},{1.2,3.21,.43,5.,23}};
```

problem (a), output like this:

```
one     1.2
two    3.21
three   .43
four     5.
five     23
```

problem (b), output like this:

```
one      1.2
two      3.21
three     .43
four     5.
five    23
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? `Grid` seems like a good option: `Grid[Transpose@inTable, Alignment -> {{Left, Right}}]`

Comment: @Öskå If I use Grid, I lose access to TableHeadings, and this approach doesn't solve the decimal alignment problem.

Comment: Yes it does: `Grid[Transpose@inTable, Alignment -> {{Left, "."}}]`. And you can just add the heading manually in the list.

Comment: In other words, just look at `Grid` with the `Alignment` and `Dividers` options. Then you might need `Prepend` to insert headings manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't revised this code for 5 years but think it should do what you need for a):

```
sortableTable[Transpose@inTable, Alignment -> {{Left,Right}, Center}]
```

and for b)

```
sortableTable[Transpose@inTable, Alignment -> {{Right, "."}, Center}]
```

[image]

```
Clear[sortableTable];

Options[sortableTable] = 
  Flatten[{TableHeadings -> {None, None}, Options[Grid]}];

SyntaxInformation[
   sortableTable] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, OptionsPattern[]}};

sortableTable::usage = "\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"sortableTable\", \"MB\"]\)[\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"data\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)] takes a list of data \
and returns a table which can be sorted by clicking on column \
headers. Styling options are the saem as for \!\(\*
StyleBox[\"Grid\", \"MB\"]\). Table headings are entered by \
specifying values for teh option TableHeadings. This option functions \
identically to the same option to \!\(\*
StyleBox[\"TableForm\", \"MB\"]\).";

sortableTable::header = "Headers need to be entered as a list.";
sortableTable::row = "Row labels  need to be entered as a list.";
sortableTable::opts = 
  "TableHeadings must be a list with a maximum length 2, containing \
specifications for row and column headings.";

sortableTable[data_List, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  DynamicModule[{gridOptions, rows, columns, rowOptions, 
    columnOptions, headings, labels, tmp, i = 1, 
    tableOptions = OptionValue[TableHeadings]},

   If[Length[tableOptions] === 1, 
    tableOptions = {None, tableOptions[[1]]}];
   If[tableOptions === {}, tableOptions = {None, None}];
   If[Length[tableOptions] > 2, Message[sortableTable::opts]; Abort[]];

   gridOptions = FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Grid]];

   {rows, columns} = Dimensions[data];

   (* get the value of the TableHeadings options *)
   {rowOptions, 
     columnOptions} = tableOptions;

   (* if the user doesn't want headers then make a blank list *)

   If[columnOptions === None, headings = Table[" ", {j, columns}]];

   (* if the value of the header option is not None then check to \
ensure it is a list *)

   If[columnOptions =!= None && ! VectorQ[columnOptions], 
    Message[sortableTable::header]; Abort[]];

   (* if the value of the header option is not None, 
   and was entered as a list then check the list length *)

   If[columnOptions =!= None && VectorQ[columnOptions],
    Which[
     Length[columnOptions] === columns, headings = columnOptions,
     Length[columnOptions] >= columns, 
     headings = columnOptions[[1 ;; columns]],
     Length[columnOptions] < columns, 
     headings = 
      Flatten[{columnOptions, 
        Table[" ", {columns - Length[columnOptions]}]}]
     ]
    ];

   (* if the value of the row option is not None then check to ensure \
it is a list *)

   If[rowOptions =!= None && ! VectorQ[rowOptions], 
    Message[sortableTable::row]; Abort[]];

   (* if the value of the row option is not None, 
   and was entered as a list then check the list length *)

   If[rowOptions =!= None && VectorQ[rowOptions],
    Which[
     Length[rowOptions] === rows, labels = rowOptions,
     Length[rowOptions] >= rows, labels = rowOptions[[1 ;; rows]],
     Length[rowOptions] < rows, 
     labels = 
      Flatten[{rowOptions, Table[" ", {rows - Length[rowOptions]}]}]
     ]
    ];

   Which[
    rowOptions === None && columnOptions === None, 
    Grid[data, gridOptions],
    rowOptions === None,
    (* no row labels *)
    Dynamic[
     tmp = SortBy[data, #[[i]] &];
     Deploy@
      Grid[Join[{Table[
          With[{j = j}, 
           EventHandler[
            headings[[j]], {"MouseClicked" :> (i = j)}]], {j, 
           columns}]}, tmp], gridOptions],
     TrackedSymbols :> {i}],

    rowOptions =!= None && columnOptions =!= None,
    (* else add row labels *)
    Dynamic[
     tmp = 
      SortBy[Transpose[Join[{labels}, Transpose[data]]], #[[i]] &];
     Deploy@Grid[
       Join[
        {Join[{EventHandler["     ", {"MouseClicked" :> (i = 1)}]}, 
          Table[With[{j = j}, 
            EventHandler[
             headings[[j]], {"MouseClicked" :> (i = j + 1)}]], {j, 
            columns}]]}, tmp],
       gridOptions],
     TrackedSymbols :> {i}]
    ]
   ];
```

Now a test showing the use of table headings:

```
data2 = RandomInteger[{1, 20}, {5, 4}];

(* some Grid options *)

opts = {Background -> {None, {GrayLevel[0.75], {White, 
       GrayLevel[0.9]}}},
   BaseStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 11],
   Dividers -> {{GrayLevel[1], {GrayLevel[.9]}, 
      GrayLevel[1]}, {GrayLevel[.2], GrayLevel[.2], {False}, 
      GrayLevel[.2]}},
   Alignment -> {{Left, {Right}}},
   ItemSize -> {{6, {7}}},
   ItemStyle -> {{Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Bold, 
       12]}, {Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 
       12], {1 -> 
        Directive[FontFamily -> "Helvetica", Bold, 13, White]}}},
   Spacings -> {1, 1}};
```

[image]

In this version I did not sort on the first column but that can be added.

Comment: Above and beyond. Thank you.